# Avoiding QueryDSL Q-Types by pattern

Tags: java, spring, jpa, design-patterns, querydsl

I'd like to realize a generic **Data Access Object (DAO)** with the aim to globally manage **CRUD** operations on my **JPA**-based project (based on **Java EE 6**).

My `CrudGenericDAO` interface may be as follows:

```
public interface CrudGenericDAO<T, ID extends Serializable> {

    // Returns the number of entities available.
    public long count();

    // Deletes the entity with the given id.
    public void delete(ID id);

    // Deletes the given entities.
    public void delete(Iterable<? extends T> entities);

    // Deletes a given entity.
    public void delete(T entity);

    // Deletes all entities managed by the repository.
    public void deleteAll();

    // Returns whether an entity with the given id exists.
    public boolean exists(ID id);

    // Returns all instances of the type.
    public Iterable<T> findAll();

    // Returns all instances of the type with the given IDs.
    public Iterable<T> findAll(Iterable<ID> ids);

    // Retrieves an entity by its id.
    public T findOne(ID id);

    // Saves all given entities.
    <S extends T>Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> entities);

    // Saves a given entity.
    <S extends T> save(S entity);

}
```

Now, I'm looking for a reliable way to implement my Generic DAO by using **QueryDSL**:
The main idea is to avoid **Q-Types** for classes that inherit my `CrudGenericDAO` implementation.

Please, feel free to suggest me which design pattern could be, in your opinion, the best in order to achieve the described goal.

---

### Note:

**Spring Framework** provides this kind of solution, but:

- I cannot use it into my project;
- The Spring implementation is complete but broad, thus it results non-trivial to understand: I'm looking for something simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PathBuilder: http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.2.0/apidocs/com/mysema/query/types/path/PathBuilder.html

Usage example from the JavaDoc:

```
PathBuilder<User> user = new PathBuilder<User>(User.class, "user");
Predicate filter = user.getString("firstName").eq("Bob");
List<User> users = query.from(user).where(filter).list(user);
```